# Cannot find type 'ParseCloud' in scope - Back4App ios implementation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, back4app

I am developing an ios app using Swift, Xcode, and back4app(Parse). I am trying to write an application launched function that connects to a function on the back end but am receiving this error. Any help would be great! Thank you in advance.

```
struct CloudUser: ParseCloud {
      typealias ReturnType = String
      var functionJobName: String
      var username: String
      var password: String
      var email: String
    }
    
    let cloudUser = CloudUser(functionJobName: "userRecord", username: self.userName.text!, password: self.password.text!, email: self.email.text!)
    cloudUser.runFunction { result in
          switch result {
          case .success(let response):
            print("Response from cloud function sumNumbers: \(response)")
          case .failure(let error):
            assertionFailure("Error calling cloud function sumNumbers: \(error)")
          }
        }
```

Error: Cannot find type 'ParseCloud' in scope

Comment: did you create ParseCloud in your project?

Comment: The answer below solved it thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ParseCloud` isn't in scope, it seems you didn't add `import ParseSwift` at the top of your file. Make sure you [installed](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift#installation) the SDK properly. The preferred way is Swift Package Manager, but cocoapods and carthage should work as well.

Be sure to look at the [Playground files](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/tree/main/ParseSwift.playground/Pages) for examples on how to use the Swift SDK:

```swift
import ParseSwift

//: Create your own value typed `ParseCloud` type.
struct Hello: ParseCloud {

    //: Return type of your Cloud Function
    typealias ReturnType = String

    //: These are required by `ParseCloud`, you can set the default value to make it easier
    //: to use.
    var functionJobName: String = "hello"
}

//: Create another `ParseCloud` type.
struct TestCloudCode: ParseCloud {

    //: Return type of your Cloud Function
    typealias ReturnType = [String: Int]

    //: These are required by `ParseCloud`, you can set the default value to make it easier
    //: to use.
    var functionJobName: String = "testCloudCode"

    //: If your cloud function takes arguments, they can be passed by creating properties:
    var argument1: [String: Int]
}

//: Create another `ParseCloud` type.
struct TestCloudCodeError: ParseCloud {

    //: Return type of your Cloud Function
    typealias ReturnType = String

    //: These are required by `ParseCloud`, you can set the default value to make it easier
    //: to use.
    var functionJobName: String = "testCloudCodeError"
}

/*: Assuming you have the Cloud Function named "hello" on your parse-server:
     // main.js
     Parse.Cloud.define('hello', async (request) => {
       console.log('From client: ' + JSON.stringify(request));
       return 'Hello world!';
     });
 */
let hello = Hello()

// Using async/await, the Playgounds shows how to use a completion handler
do {
  let result = try await hello.runFunction() 
  print("Response from cloud function: \(response)")

} catch {

  print("Error calling cloud function: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I had 'Parse' imported but not 'ParseSwift'