# How to access returned value from Parse Cloud function - Javascript backend

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, back4app

I am currently creating an ios app using swift with parse/back4app as my back end. I am trying to return a query result from my server to my application. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to access the returned data. Attach is the console output of the returned data, my cloud function, and the application function catching the returned query. Thank you in advance

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**:

```
<UserLocation: 0x6000009c49c0, objectId: 4491TlDn5z, localId: (null)> {
latitude = "-26.2041028";
longitude = "28.0473051";
username = test0;
```

}

**APPLICATION FUNCTION**:

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "UserLocationRecord",
                            withParameters: ["username": self.userName,
                                             "longitude": locationInfo.coordinate.longitude,
                                             "latitude": locationInfo.coordinate.latitude,
                                            ])
            { result, error in
            let stat = result as! NSArray
            print(stat[0])
            print(error)
            }
```

**JAVASCRIPT CLOUD/SERVER FUNCTION**:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("UserLocationRecord", (request) => {

  const UserLocation = Parse.Object.extend("UserLocation");
  const userLocation = new Parse.Query(UserLocation);

  let query = new Parse.Query("UserLocation");
  query.equalTo("username", request.params.username);
  let results = query.find()
  return results;
});
```

**LOGS FROM CONSOLE OF SERVER:**

```
2022-02-14T20:48:07.636Z - Ran cloud function UserLocationRecord for user BlSOr7wulW with:
  Input: {"latitude":-33.8634,"longitude":151.211,"username":"test0"}
  Result: [{"longitude":28.0473051,"username":"test0","latitude":-26.2041028,"createdAt":"2022-02-13T03:37:49.526Z","updatedAt":"2022-02-13T03:40:24.450Z","objectId":"4491TlDn5z","__type":"Object","className":"UserLocation"}]
```

**Already investigated:**
It is not an Array, or Dictionary despite its look. i tried to index, it both with bracket and dot notation and nothing happens. In addition I tried using a for each loop and got an error back saying results in not iterable. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71097819/cannot-find-type-parsecloud-in-scope-back4app-ios-implementation) it looks like you are trying to use [ParseSwift](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift) and the [iOS Objective-C](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX) frameworks in the same app. You shouldn't be doing this and should either choose ParseSwift or the Objective-C framework. ParseSwift is newer, [has more features](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/1356#issuecomment-779288554), and is the recommended option for those starting new apps in Swift. If you are use the ParseCloud protocol from your previous question you don't have to worry about this issue.

The results in your question look to be an array of Parse objects, in particular `[UserLocation]`, not an `NSArray`.

Comment: Okay I see. Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you mark my response as the answer?